# Constant expression member array of unknown bounds

Tags: c++

I have a type that looks more or less like:

```
struct validate_set
{
    std::string_view key;
    span<std::string_view> allowed_values;
};
```

The jist is that I have a collection of these that I can then pass to a separate function that will validate a set of key : value pairs against their allowed values. The problem is that I can't construct an array of these like so:

```
constexpr std::array allowedValues{
    validate_set{ "foo"sv, { "bar"sv, "baz"sv } },
    validate_set{ "hello"sv, { "world"sv } }
};
```

As I've been unable to determine a type to use for `span`. The issue seems pretty obvious: the array needs storage, and it would seem as though there's no "inline" way to do so. `std::array` - or just a normal array - is obviously out of the question since that affects the signature of `validate_set` and would inhibit the ability to create arrays of these structs. `std::initializer_list` doesn't work either since that just constructs a temporary. Are there any cool tricks that I'm overlooking or don't know about?

FWIW there are two okay-ish backup plans.

**Backup plan #1**

Use nested null characters. E.g.:

```
constexpr std::array allowedValues{
    validate_set{ "foo"sv, "bar\0baz"sv },
    validate_set{ "hello"sv, "world"sv }
};
```

**Backup plan #2**

Force the `std::initializer_list` storage. E.g.:

```
constexpr std::initializer_list list0 = { "bar"sv, "baz"sv };
constexpr std::initializer_list list1 = { "world"sv };
constexpr std::array allowedValues{
    validate_set{ "foo"sv, list0 },
    validate_set{ "hello"sv, list1 }
};
```

Option 1 is the current winner as I'd really prefer to allow consumers to declare things inline.

Comment: Are the 'validated_set's meant to be constructed only in a constexpr context?

Comment: Ideally yes, though there's no reason why it must. That said, heap allocation is a no-go

Comment: I haven't tried this, but would it not be possible then to give validate_set a constexpr constructor and make span an initializer_list?

Comment: @linuxfever that wouldn't be any different than the usage I've already described with `initializer_list`. The backing array is a temporary. Initializing via a constructor wouldn't change that

Comment: I've written a solution which requires changing the signature of `validate_set` to account for the size of allowed values, but I've kept their creation very similar to the one you've posted. Have a look here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/141f84a86391537d and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: `tuple` is an interesting way to go about it, but is not easily enumerable

Comment: True. It all depends on the final use case... do you need to enumerate the elements or just iterate through them? If the latter, then with the boost hana library you can easily iterate through the elements one by one or unpack them in one go. If the former, then all you can use is std::get<I> which limits you to compile time constants and may not be flexible enough for you.

Comment: Any news on this? Another idea I had is to use a boost static_vector<T,N>, which behaves like a normal vector but uses stack memory instead of heap and can grow up to the pre-specified capacity N. If you define N large enough (say, using a macro), then the signature of validate_set doesn't need to change. Let me know your thoughts